# Ensemble learning with Encog

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network, encog, ensemble-learning

Is it possible to have an example on how to create an ensamble learner with Encog for time series forecasting?

I was thinking at a iRPROP+ ensamble learner.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensemble learning is still in the process of being added to Encog.  More examples will be added when it is finalized.  You can add a feature request on the issues page if you would like to suggest a specific example.  https://github.com/encog/encog-java-core/issues

Answer (score 0):

One technique you could try would be to simply aggregate the output of several networks together after each epoch. In order to have different networks, you will have to initialize each network with different starting weights.